# How set GADInterstitial AdMob showing Fullscreen when i 5 touches

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, admob

Why don't work admob ads, this is example from my cod

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *BanerAppear =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerApearAdMob)];
            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:BanerAppear];


self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-5576225790959277/7656083543"];
    request1 = [GADRequest request];
    request1.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request1];
```

[image]